# Reading InputStream as UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, inputstream

I'm trying to read from a `text/plain` file over the internet, line-by-line. The code I have right now is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://kuehldesign.net/test.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList();
String readLine;

while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(readLine);
}

for (String line : lines) {
    out.println("> " + line);
}
```

The file, `test.txt`, contains `¡Hélló!`, which I am using in order to test the encoding.

When I review the `OutputStream` (`out`), I see it as `> ¬°H√©ll√≥!`. I don't believe this is a problem with the `OutputStream` since I can do `out.println("é");` without problems.

Any ideas for reading form the `InputStream` as UTF-8? Thanks!

Comment: The HTTP protocol specifies the encoding. Why aren’t you using a library API that handles that for you? You should never have to guess the encoding like this. I don’t mean to be negative: you’re doing great! I just wonder whether there isn’t an easier way.

Comment: I won't have access to the server which is serving the `text/plain` file, unfortunately, and it's not using a UTF-8 encoding. I wasn't aware of any good network libraries; any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), I wouldn’t think you would have to specify the encoding at all. I am surprised they give you a byte stream! You do have access to underlying [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), from which you can check the Content-Encoding, then open an InputStreamReader with the correct argument. A quick check of the source doesn’t turn up anything that seems to do that for you, which seems pretty darned lame and error prone, so I probably missed something.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Solved my own problem. This line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

needs to be:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

or since Java 7:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure that form of the constructor won’t raise an exception on invalid input.  You need to use the with a `CharsetDecoder dec` argument. This is same Java design bug that the `OutputStreamWriter` constructors have: only one of the four actually condescends to tell you when something goes wrong. You again have to use the fancy `CharsetDecoder dec` argument there, too. The only safe and sane thing to do is to consider all other constructors deprecated, because they cannot be trusted to behave.

Comment: Since Java 7 it is possible to write the provide the Charset as a Constant not as a String `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Answer (score 18):

```
String file = "";

try {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    String UTF8 = "utf8";
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
            UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);
    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        file += str;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Try this,.. :-)

Comment: Instead of file += str, create a StringBuilder and append to that.  The compiler might be able to optimize the string appending, but it's likely creating a lot of garbage

Comment: If you want to convert a BufferedReader into a string, use Apache Commons, do not reinvent the wheal: String myStr = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString( myBufferedReaderInstance);

Comment: UTF8 = "utf8", nice variable ;)

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem every time it finds a special character marks it as ��. to solve this, I tried using the encoding: ISO-8859-1

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("txtPath"),"ISO-8859-1"));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

}
```

I hope this can help anyone who sees this post.

Comment: Could you please tell what is the characters not supported in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the constructor `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`, bad characters are silently replaced. To change this behaviour, use a `CharsetDecoder` :

```
public static Reader newReader(Inputstream is) {
  new InputStreamReader(is,
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
      .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
      .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
  );
}
```

Then catch `java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException`.