# java.lang.Error: Invalid UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, finance, fix-protocol

I am getting this error when trying to process trades through my trading application and when it is communicating with FIX.

```
     java.lang.Error: Invalid UTF-8 Encoding
     at javolution.io.Struct$UTF8String.get(Struct.java:1105)
```

I use UTF-8 encoding and it has been specified in each POM file of my application.It is happening when the trade comes into the application.
Has anyone come across this error ever ?

Comment: Are you sure the input is even supposed to be in UTF-8?

Comment: @Esailija Yes the input is supposed to be in UTF-8.

Comment: It seems related to the presence of a byte-order marker in the file. The closest report I could quickly find is this here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97329_03/web.902/a88894/adx19paj.htm#1006476

Comment: It is using Hazelcast SerialisationHelper for encoding the data.Could they possibly be a problem in encoding the object that has been send to the SerializationHelper of Hazelcast ?

Comment: seeing more of the stacktrace might prove to be beneficial

Comment: java.lang.Error: Invalid UTF-8 Encoding at javolution.io.Struct$UTF8String.get(Struct.java:1105)

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE:

Looks like what you've run into are a couple of existing bugs: [Fault in handling of UTF8Strings within the Struct class](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVOLUTION-41) and [XMLStreamReaderImpl ignoring xml encoding attribute?](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVOLUTION-43)

> Passing certain Strings to the UTF8String set method results in the
>   field boundary of the memory block which the UTF8String is mapped to
>   in the backing ByteBuffer being exceeded. This appears to result from
>   certain UTF-8 multi-byte characters expanding the string.

---

Seems there's a problem with the data you're processing or there's a bug in the library. Take a look at the [source code of UTF8ByteBufferReader](https://svn.java.net/svn/javolution~svn/trunk/javolution/core-java/src/main/java/javolution/io/UTF8ByteBufferReader.java). The exception is being thrown from the following method

> private int read2(byte b) throws IOException

towards the bottom of that method you'll see

> throw new CharConversionException("Invalid UTF-8 Encoding");

I would double-check that the data you're receiving is in fact UTF-8, because that library doesn't seem to think it is...

---

If all you're doing is trying to decode a UTF8 stream, you can just use regular Java for that. There are a lot of [UTF8 examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8) online. Also, you might need to use Apache's [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html).

You can also just read in the bytes and periodically use [Charset#decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) of [StandardCharsets.UTF_8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8)

Comment: Yes you are right. There must be a problem in the data. However, I do not have an instance of the trade data that's causing the problem. That is why I was searching whether there is a bug in the code.

Comment: just use your program to record the data (into a file) instead of processing it. then, look at what you've recorded. as someone already mentioned, one possible culprit is BOM (byte order mark), although i don't think it plays a crucial role in UTF-8 processing, it's just an indicator that the data that comes after it will be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: there are seem to be bugs in javolution. i updated my answer with some links

Comment: I have the version 5.5.1 of javolution in my project. Isn't it the latest ? I think it will have this fix in it if then.

Comment: i don't think so. the status of both bugs is "open"

Comment: Oh thanks for informing me about that. So what solution would you recommend. It is a critical issue. :(

Comment: well, i haven't heard about javolution until i answered this question. but if all you need to do is to decode a UTF8 stream, you can use regular Java for that. i've updated my answer with some links.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19510/discussion-between-abcd-and-andrey)

Answer (score 1):

The FIX standard uses ASCII, not UTF-8.