# How can i read valid utf-8 characters 0xC2 0x85 from an input stream which are outside the byte range in java?

Tags: java

I have an input stream that contains valid utf8 characters 0xC2 0x85 (U+0085). How can I read and print this correctly in java? using byte array doesn't help i think as 0x85 is out of range. Basically, I need to read utf8 characters coming from a socket in java which contains 0xC2 0x85

Comment: Is this any use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8

Comment: It doesn't help. I am having something like this.... byte [] buffer = new byte [10240]; socket.getInputStream().read(buffer)

Comment: Why do you think `0x85` is out of range?

Comment: bytes are signed in Java, that only means that 0x85 (dec 133) will be interpreted (as byte) as 133-256=-123. That's no problem. Anyway, that's irrelevant for your goal, to translate bytes as characters, use an `InputStreamReader` that does the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a valid stream in UTF-8 (is) then use

```
   Reader rdr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
```

this will convert UTF-8 bytes into Java chars