# How to remove � from a String?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, bufferedreader

What is that char `�`? and how to remove it from a String? I got it from a `BufferedReader` and i got it because i read the contents in a char array and this array has to be assigned to a particular size.So, i got the String like that `"aaaaaaa����"`, and I tried `trim` and `subString` but didn't change anything:

```
 String a = "aaaaaaa����";
//subString
    int i = a.lastIndexOf("a");
    a = a.substring(0, i+1);
//trim
    a = a.trim();
```

And this is my way to read the input:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
char[] a = new char[1000];
int line;
String responseLine, server_response = "";
while((line = in.read(a)) != -1) {
      responseLine = String.valueOf(a);
      server_response = server_response + responseLine;
     }
in.close();
return server_response;
```

Comment: Probably there are encoding problems?

Comment: @donfuxx I have doubts in that too, but I don't know how to handle it

Comment: @Wooble I'm pretty sure that this is not related to the data as I'm already now what's the data

Comment: You open a `Reader` without specifying the encoding; as such the default JRE ecoding will be used. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, as the problem not comes from reading the input string, it comes from converting the non-filled char_array to a String

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, but that may very well be the problem. Don't forget that a `Reader` takes the bytes of the stream and converts them to chars _depending on the encoding_. You never send `char`s down the wire, only bytes. The fact that you have bizarre characters showing up in your resulting strings is a sign that you don't use the correct encoding. Ultimately, a `String` is an array of `char`s, not bytes

Comment: Notably, a Java `char` is a very different thing from a C `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found a way to solve that, it's not a professional one but efficient enough.
all i had to do is filling the `char array` with *white spaces* just before starting the `while loop` and then after receiving the whole response i have just to *trim it* before returning it :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
char[] a = new char[1000];
int line;
String responseLine, server_response = "";
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ //
      a[i] = ' ';                  // this is the for loop i added
    }                              //
while((line = in.read(a)) != -1) {
      responseLine = String.valueOf(a);
      server_response = server_response + responseLine;
      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){ //
          a[i] = ' ';                    // this is the for loop i added
        }                                //
     }
in.close();
return server_response.trim();     // this is where i return the response trimmed
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely to be an encoding problem; you do not specify the encoding on your `InputStreamReader`, as such the system default is used.

Try and use:

```
new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

instead.

If you are still stuck with JDK 6, replace `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` with `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`.

If you are unsure what encoding is used at the other end, you should not use a `Reader` but read the contents into a byte array. Then you can use a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) to try and map the bytes read into one or more encodings.

Example:

```
StandardCharsets.ASCII.newDecoder()
```

Comment: What didn't solve the problem? Have you tried the `CharsetDecoder` way? Do you at least know the encoding used by the other end?

Answer (score 1):

Try with unicode

Unicode corresponding to � is `\ufffd`

```
String str0 = "aaaaaaa����";
System.out.println(str0.replaceAll("\ufffd", ""));
```

Comment: it didn't do anything also

Comment: Except that that display character is often used for "any character I don't have a glyph for".

Comment: @chrylis yea it may be that, do you have an idea to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

you could handle it like this:

```
System.out.println("aaaaaaa����".replace("�", ""));
```

remaining string will be `aaaaaaa`.

I recommend to investigate the input source though and figure out *why* you get those chars there. Probably there is somewhere an issue with the encoding.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't agree to save and tells me `some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252"`

Comment: seems like this encoding is not supported. Try using utf-8 encoding in your reader like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4964652/2399024

Comment: the problem not comes from reading the input string, it comes from converting the non-filled char_array to a String

Answer (score 0):

If your only expecting numbers and characters you can run a for loop on the byte array and run Char.isLetterOrDigit on each character replacing those that arent with ""

Comment: there are some special chars

Comment: This will return false if the character isn't alphanumeric So you can use this to find the special chars and set them to ""

Comment: there are some special chars that I need to be existed not to be removed

Comment: If that's the only character you need removed you can try to compare each char to that character and replace

Comment: I can't write that character into my code in order to compare it, it gives me `some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252"`

Comment: Do you know specifically what special character you want?

Comment: @MRefaat _it gives me some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252"_: are you using Eclipse IDE? Try setting your workspace text file encoding to UTF-8. You can find it in the Preferences Menu: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace, then select "Other: UTF-8" as "Text file encoding"

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen that really enabled me to read the char but it didn't replaced from the output when i made some replacing processes