# HttpResponse with special characters

Tags: java, rest, http, character-encoding

I have written a REST client for this endpoint:

```
textmap.com/ethnicity_api/api
```

However, while passing it a name string like `jennífer garcía` in the POST params, and setting encoding to UTF-8, the response that I get is not the same string. How to get the same name in the response object?
Below is how I set the request and the response thatI get:

```
httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
httpPost = new HttpPost(baseurl);
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputJSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
input.setContentType("application/json");
//input.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httpPost.setEntity(input);
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

output = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(br);
System.out.println(output);
```

Value of the name in output is : `jennï¿½fer garcï¿½a`

This is a completely different charset from what I had sent in the request. How can I get the same charset as I had sent in request?

Secondly, I want the same code to work in both Java-6 and Java-7. The above code is using Java-7 only. How can I make the code work for both these versions?

Comment: Try adding a `Accept-Charset` header to your POST request with it's value set to `UTF-8`.

Comment: @SteveC doing that I get this now as output: `jennÃ­fer garcÃ­a`. STill I do not get the original string back as response :(  This is the code I added: `httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");`

Comment: Can you prove that `inputJSON` is in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `BufferedReader` is [breaking the UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8), so this is actually pretty unrelated to HTTP. On a side note, the br may [not be needed at all](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: That's the way to go.