# "Disallowed Key Characters" error in json output

Tags: java, json, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I'm trying to execute API and try to get `json` response, but I'm getting error as `"Disallowed Key Characters"` for `bf.readLine()`.

Following is the code that I'm trying to use. But when I run the request url in web browser I'm getting response without issue.But by using java code I'm unable to extract data. Please help

```
String uri = "http://192.168.77.6/Ivr_ABN_API/?id?id="
            + mobile;
    URL url;
    Gson json = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);
        json = new Gson();

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        access_token = db.getAccessTokenFromDB();
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        System.out.println("URL:" + uri);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();
        resCode = Integer.toString(status);


                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                System.out.println("bf.readLine() - "+bf.readLine());

                while ((output = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
                    System.out.println("output is "+output);
                    resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
                    resDesc = obj.getString("COUNT");

                }


        connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: You are not specifying a charset for the `InputStreamReader`. JSON usually uses UTF-8. Also, JSON is not line-oriented, so `readLine()` probably isn't the right approach to use anyway. Consider using `Gson.fromJson()` instead, which takes a `Reader` as input.

Comment: take a look at this >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

instead of

```
 BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

because you need to add encoding technique by which a `BufferedReader` able to encode any special character in proper format.

Hope this might help you.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution for the question and posting for your reference.

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
```