# Read Layout xml file with input reader

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, xposed

I am trying to read a layout XML file.

```
String file="res/layout/activity_main.xml";
InputStream in=mCurrentActivity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
                InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while((line=br.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    XposedBridge.log(line);
                 }
```

This is my code and this one is my corresponding XML file
the output that I get:
[image: the output that I get:]

Since its my term project I need to figure it out fast(have 2 days left) so any help would be appreciated..

**SOLUTION**

I didn't have the id so first I get the id with :

```
int layoutId =mCurrentActivity.getResources().getIdentifier("activity_main", "layout",mCurrentActivity.getPackageName());
```

and then :

```
XmlResourceParser s = mCurrentActivity.getResources().getLayout(layoutId);
```

Thanks to **Mike M**.

Comment: That's not unexpected. Layouts are compiled into a special binary format when they're packed into your apk. You could use `Context#getResources.getLayout(R.layout.activity_main)` to get an `XmlResourceParser`, and then loop over that to get all the tags and attributes and values. It's not terribly complicated, but it does take a little work. There's probably even an existing solution out there somewhere.

Comment: I should mention, though, that that's only give you the layout for the current configuration. If you need to access layouts in other configurations, you'd have to do it a little differently.

Comment: first of all thanks for fast answer the problem is i only have the activityr object so are there anyway to get it with an activity object?

Comment: i use xposed and hook application and get the activity wich means that i need to do it without id too(R.layout. ...)

Comment: so even if i get the context, i need to get layout without id

Comment: @MikeM. maybe the other way that you mentioned is the key?

Comment: An `Activity` is a `Context`, so you can call `getResources()` on that; e.g., `mCurrentActivity.getResources()...`. And, if you know the name of the layout in that app, you can use the `Resources#getIdentifier()` method to get the numerical ID for it; e.g., `int layoutId = mCurrentActivity.getResources().getIdentifier("activity_main", "layout", mCurrentActivity.getPackageName())`;.

Comment: Thanks A lot MIKE !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Search gets me quite similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964640/reading-inputstream-as-utf-8). The main idea for solving your problem, I guess, is that you should specify encoding.

Accordingly to your case try to change the code in that way:

```
String file="res/layout/activity_main.xml";
InputStream in=mCurrentActivity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
{
    XposedBridge.log(line);
}
```

or

```
String file="res/layout/activity_main.xml";
InputStream in=mCurrentActivity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
{
    XposedBridge.log(line);
}
```

or try to use another encoding variant despite UTF-8.

I suppose it depends on what type of encoding did you set in your.xml file

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Encoding is not the problem. The "XML" file is not plain XML but binary XML. Therefore simply changing the encoding does not change anything!

Answer (score 0):

The XML file you are trying to read is not plain XML bin binary XML format. Therefore trying to read it via common `Reader` will not work.

You can use e.g. the library [AXML](https://github.com/xgouchet/AXML) to load such binary xml files:

```
String file="res/layout/activity_main.xml";
InputStream in = mCurrentActivity.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file));
Document doc = new CompressedXmlParser().parseDOM(in);
```

Comment: hey robert , i get an out of bounds exception when trying to initilaize document,

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=1480 index=1483

Comment: @myprogramistoobusywitherrors If you think it is a bug of AXML create an issue here: https://github.com/xgouchet/AXML/issues